# .How do pseudo-terminal restore the character into a complete command when I enter one character every time?

Tags: c, linux, pty

I'm  developing pseudo-terminal application using linux c .How do  "/dev/ptmx"  restore the character   into a complete command , when I enter one character to STDIN_FILENO every time.

For example:

```
write (master_fd, "l", 1);
write (master_fd, "s", 1);
write (master_fd, "/r/n", 2);
```

Pseudo-terminal  will restore my input into the "ls" command. How to develop a similar function to restore a complete command ？ This is just a simple case ,  it will be more complicated when  user enters backspace or the tab key .
 Is there any relevant source code can be found？

Comment: Check out libreadline: http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html

Comment: see also: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Text-Terminal-HOWTO-7.html

Comment: I notice this line: write (master_fd, "/r/n", 2); has a bug.  Specifically, the '\n' can be one or two characters, depending on the underlying OS.  DOS/Windows is x0a0d' while max, linux/unix are one char.  so the value '2' will fail to write the whole '\r\n' string under DOS/Windows